# Page detected as UTF-8 by browsers when it has 'ISO-8859-1' as meta charset

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm dealing with a site transfer, and in the process my charset got fouled up. At first, I transferred all files with no alterations, and the files on the new server showed `<?>` icons for special characters. A glance at the browser's character encoding (Chrome and FF) told me it was auto-detecting UTF-8. The meta charset of pages is set to ISO-8859-1. Copy is drawn from various tables in multiple databases (don't ask).

On the original site, all displayed as it should. On the new site, `<?>`... I dug into it, found default charset ="UTF-8" in php.ini, set it to nothing. Now the majority of pages on the site display fine, the browser recognizes the meta charset tag, everybody's happy; that is, until I navigate to a folder off root.

The files in this folder, although their meta charset is ISO-8859-1, are somehow telling the browser to be read as UTF-8, which means I'm seeing `<?>` on these pages. If I set the browser to read as ISO-8859-1, then it displays fine. Auto-detect resets it to UTF-8. Any ideas?

Thank you!

**Update (added from comment below):**

I ran the page through the [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) as recommended by martinstoeckli, and it tells me that the HTTP Content-Type is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` while the meta tag is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>`, which gives me a **Conflicting character encoding declarations** error. Crazy thing is, I can't for the life of me figure out where the UTF-8 declaration is coming from! It's nowhere in any file, all files were saved UTF-8 w/out BOM, the php.ini is set to declare no default, the folder's .htaccess is set like PatomaS suggests.

(For what it's worth, Mozilla's Web Sniffer confirms HTTP header Content-Type of `text/html; charset=utf-8`.)

**Update:**
While we did not reach a solution to this problem as I posed it, I did decide that the best way to resolve my character encoding issues is to refactor everything to use UTF-8 encoding. Of course, this probably means you will see me on here with more exciting newbie questions like "Just why won't utf8-encode() do my łâùñdrÿ?"

Of course, that means the mystery remains: what is causing the server to send HTTP Content-type charset headers of UTF-8 when it appears that everything is configured differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are files may have BOM (Byte Order Mark) in them. To ensure open a file with notepad++ and check Coding menu , also you can select convert to ansi as an option for a test.

BTW using utf-8 everywhere is a better -long term- approach that i can suggest.

Comment: I use Sublime Text 2, and all files are saved as UTF-8 without BOM.

For the long term, I do plan on converting everything to UTF-8; for now, I have to get the characters to display properly, then take the next step. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I realize that attempting to work this out is like putting the horse and wheels into the cart and asking why I'm not getting anywhere. I am accepting this as the answer, because even though it doesn't specifically solve this problem (why is the server sending anomalous HTTP charset header?), it solves the greater issue of poor encoding practices by recommending a sensible long-term solution.

Comment: There is a nice explanation on declaration issues here ; http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations btw you may also try .htaccess add charset solution and the one explained at http://www.justskins.com/forums/php4-1-2-incorrect-7845.html , cys

Comment: Could the web server be putting a default charset=utf8 in the content-type when nothing else about the file being served tells it what to put there?

Comment: ashnazg: Yes , i had faced similar situations before, Sadly when migrating from one server to another, especially when using backup managers or compressors to move all files at once,  new host may have put that byte order mark to all files automatically. So i always keep ftp downloaded backups in my harddisk.

Answer (score 5):

PHP 5.6 comes with a new default charset directive set to `UTF-8`, in some case this may be a problem with pages served in metatag as latin1 and may be cause of conflicts in validation service, you can override this directive by calling `ini_set('default_charset', 'iso-8859-1')` in your scripts.

For doing that put on each php file you want to be coded to latin1 this piece of code at the beginning of your scripts:

example: `index.php`

```
<?php
  $server_root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
  $config_serv = "$server_root/php/config.php";
  include("$config_serv");
?>
```

Then create a folder "php" under your root website and put this piece of code into `config.php`:

example: `config.php`

```
<?php
  ##########################################################################
  # Server Directive - Override default_charset utf-8 to latin1 in php.ini #
  ##########################################################################
  @ini_set('default_charset', 'ISO-8859-1');
?>
```

If your php.ini is set to latin1 (`ISO-8859-1`) and you want serve a utf-8 (unicode) page you can force encoding using the same way but putting instead of iso-8859-1, utf-8. Look at that:

example: `config.php`

```
<?php
  ##########################################################################
  # Server Directive - Override default_charset latin1 to utf-8 in php.ini #
  ##########################################################################
  @ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
?>
```

I hope you find my answer useful, I solved my problem in this way! I had problems with firefox and its html/css validator that given my pages as latin1 and the headers as utf-8. This conflict is solved! I finally solved using my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a wonderful [W3-checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) for all kind of encoding problems.

Comment: Thank you for this. I ran the page through this checker, and it tells me that the HTTP Content-Type is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` while the meta tag is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>`, which gives me a **Conflicting character encoding declarations** error. Crazy thing is, I can't for the life of me figure out where the UTF-8 declaration is coming from! It's nowhere in any file, all files were saved UTF-8 w/out BOM, the php.ini is set to declare no default, the folder's .htaccess is set like PatomaS suggests.

Help?!

Comment: @somewhatsapient - So then it seems clear to me, you declared the page in the meta tags as ISO-8859-1, but you are storing the file as UTF-8. This cannot work. If you want it to be ISO-8859-1, you should tell your editor (Sublime), to use this encoding instead of UTF-8. If you want it to be UTF-8, you need to declare it as UTF-8 in the meta tags. The encoding of the file and the meta tag has to match.

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't solve the problem. To test this out, I also created a dead simple HTML file, saved as UTF-8 with `<meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>` declaration, and the issue does **not** arise; however, if I save the exact same file as .php, I get the conflicting declarations. Again, this only happens in this one folder. If I move the PHP file that is creating declaration conflict between HTTP and meta _to another folder,_ it declares cleanly and once with the meta tag only.

Comment: @somewhatsapient - Did you check if there is a `.htaccess` file in this directory?

Comment: there is, and it's configured to AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1 to .php files. I'm changing tactics and going to refactor everything to UTF-8 since no solution is forthcoming and I intended to do so eventually. Thank you!

Comment: @somewhatsapient - That's a certainly a good choice, i'm sure you won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in your root `.htaccess` for all the files you want to be iso-8859-1

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|xhtml|xml|css|js|php)$">
    AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
</FilesMatch>
```

Remember that server headers have priority over inline headers.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not have any apparent effect. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Apache could force the charset to a default value (UTF-8) even if you specify it in your code.

This options is in your httpd.conf file and is called AddDefaultCharset.
You need to comment it to let your code rules the world.

This has solved my problem.

source : https://major.io/2007/11/15/change-the-default-apache-character-set/